# How to define a type with a string length of 1 using TyperScript

Tags: typescript

When iterating through a string loop, I need to put a single character into an array, so I need to define a character array type or interface.

I want to know how to define a type with a string length of 1 using TyperScript.

Comment: That'd be `string & { length: 1 }` but you'd have to cast or validate it every time as iirc const strings for not have constant length unlike tuples

Comment: `type(['string','&', {length:1}])` from ArkType would validate/infer type it correctly I guess if you don't want making your own validator